# Unexpected error while executing my appium code on android emulator

Tags: appium, emulators

**Error**

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
> Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized.
> Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate
> the logcat output.

**Code:**

```java
package com.android.app;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class mobileAutomation {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DesiredCapabilities dcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5554");
        dcap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"android");
        dcap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.microsoft.teams");
        dcap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.microsoft.skype.teams.Launcher");
        dcap.setCapability("noReset", "true");
        //dcap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator1");
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), dcap);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `UiAutomator2`
and incluse Android Version

```
caps.setCapability("platformVersion","4.3");
```

also make sure appium server is started before running your tests